# Comparing means across non-mutually exclusive groups

Tags: anova, categorical-data, binary-data

I have 4 groups that identify different research field (animal, plant, microbe and insect). Scientists were asked to indicate in which group they belong and they were allowed to indicate more than one group - i.e. a scientist can be both in "animal" and "microbe". We then ask scientists a set of questions about time spent on research activities. We would like to compare means across groups. Normally, I'll use ANOVA but in this case the four groups are not mutually exclusive. Can I use t-test comparing each group against the rest of the population, i.e. those in the Animal group against all others? Is that appropriate? Are there better methods? I currently use R for my analysis.

Comment: Consider a single one of these proposed comparisons.and note that the people that are in both groups being compared contribute no information to identifying a difference (their data are paired but the variance of their internal differences are all zero). If you properly account for their presence you'll add nothing over leaving them out altogether.

Comment: @Fedrica Fuci time spent on research activities   -  percentage   on different classified fields or hours etc. ?

Comment: Hi @subhashc.davar, thanks for your comment. Time spent on research activities is a continuous variable, measuring the number of hours they spend on research. Respondents were free to enter any number. We also want to compare a Likert scale across groups.

Comment: @Federica. Fusi For the purpose of analysis,You can make five groups - one with mixed i.e. two or more area of specialisation. Would you post your Scale and scoring method.

Comment: @subhashc.davar It's a five-point Likert scale created by combining 5 items. The idea of a mixed group is interesting. I didn't think about it

Comment: @Glen_b thanks. If I understand correctly, you are saying that including them or not will not affect my results and, as such, using a t-test is a fine method?

Comment: You can't just throw the same numbers into both groups and treat them as independent, since those are *perfectly dependent*. If you could treat them properly (deal with the dependence) there should be no difference (they don't add any information about a difference). If you just throw them in and *pretend* they're independent. that's slightly different; the tests won't behave right if you do something like that.

Comment: @Glen_b sorry, I understand your point, but not really your solution if I want to compare across two groups. The way I am doing right now is to compare those who are part of group Plants against all others. Since the group is identified by a binary variable (=1 if they are in the group, = 0 if they are not), an individual cannot be in the both groups.

Comment: I'm just going by the statement in your question "*i.e. a scientist can be both in "animal" and "microbe"*". If you get "all others" by putting together all the ones in "animal", "microbe" and "insect" then presumably they will overlap with "plant". If you're comparing those who nominated "plant" with those who did not, that's *not sufficiently clear in your question*, which suggests the opposite; in that case there are none in common across the two groups, and the issue is moot.